# Replacing invokeMethod to intercept Controller methods

Tags: grails, groovy

I would like intercept all methods in all controllers by replacing the invokeMethod closure of the ExpandoMetaClass.

I created a new grails Project (2.3.5). Created a new Controller, called AccountController:

```
package com.invoke.test
class AccountController {
    def index() {
        System.out.println("Index Called")
    }
}
```

Then created an additional BootStrap called SecurityBootStrap:

```
class SecurityBootStrap {

def grailsApplication

def verifyMethodAccess = { String name, args ->
    log.info "Called method ${name}"
    def method = delegate.metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args)
    if (method) {
        return method.invoke(delegate, args)
    }
    return null
}

def init = { servletContext ->
    grailsApplication.controllerClasses.each { controllerClass ->
        controllerClass.clazz.metaClass.invokeMethod = verifyMethodAccess
        log.info "Replaced the invokeMethod closure on ${controllerClass.clazz}"
    }
}
}
```

After starting the application, the log is looking promising:

```
|Running Grails application
2014-06-26 15:07:26,476 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  conf.SecurityBootStrap  - Replaced the invokeMethod closure on class grails.plugin.databasemigration.DbdocController
2014-06-26 15:07:26,477 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  conf.SecurityBootStrap  - Replaced the invokeMethod closure on class com.invoke.test.AccountController
|Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/InvokeTest
```

But, when calling `http://localhost:8080/InvokeTest/account/index` the log look like:

```
Index Called
```

I expected it to be:

```
Called method index
Index Called
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with compile time meta programming but you can't do this with runtime metaprogramming.  A limitation of Groovy's runtime metaprogramming is that it only applies to method calls which are initiated from Groovy.  Much of the Grails framework is written in Java.

Example:

```
class Widget {
    def getTheAnswer() {
        42
    }
}

Widget.metaClass.getTheAnswer = { ->
    2112
}
```

When Groovy code invokes `new Widget().getTheAnswer()` the result will be 2112.  When Java code invokes `new Widget().getTheAnswer();` the result will be 42.

Comment: I added another method to the controller, `def methodTwo() { println "MethodTwo Called" }` and called it in index(). methodTwo() should now be called via `invokeMethod`, since it's being called from groovy, right? But the log shows only "MethodTwo Called".

Comment: I don't think your approach is going to work even for Groovy classes (definitely not for Java classes).  I think your class has to implement GroovyInterceptable in order for calls to existing methods to be intercepted by invokeMethod.